# Saving a Class of my variables to XML File

Tags: c#, xml, class, save

I have created a Class called "VNCVars.cs" and I want to be able to Save the data associated with all the Variables inside VNCVars to a XML file so I can load them back in on startup. I have another class called "SaveData.cs" which contains the code to generate the XML file.

I have code written that runs but my XML file is always empty.....can somebody point out what I have missed out??

```
public class VNCVars
{
    //Global Variables for VNC 1 Location
    //VNC File Location 1 Get and Set routines
    private static string strVNC1Location;
    public static string VNC1Location
    {
        get { return strVNC1Location; }
        set { strVNC1Location = value; }
    }


    //Global Variables for VNC 2 Location
    //VNC File Location 2 Get and Set routines
    private static string strVNC2Location;
    public static string VNC2Location
    {
        get { return strVNC2Location; }
        set { strVNC2Location = value; }
    }


    //Global Variables for VNC 3 Location
    //VNC File Location 3 Get and Set routines
    private static string strVNC3Location;
    public static string VNC3Location
    {
        get { return strVNC3Location; }
        set { strVNC3Location = value; }
    }
}

public class SaveXML
{

    public static void SaveData()
    {
        var SaveData = new VNCVars();

        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VNCVars));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Fanuc\SetupVars.xml");
        sr.Serialize(writer, SaveData);
        writer.Close();
    }


}
```

Then finally on my form I currently just have a button and on the click the following occurs...

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveXML.SaveData();
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated....

Comment: You can't serialize a class using static fields like that. Make the fields non-static.

Comment: I was just going to say where's the constructor

Comment: if I make them non-static then I can't access the variables from every form i have i.e. VNCVars.VNC1Location. Sorry for the basic questions but I'm fairly new to C# programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should use instance properties instead of static properties.

You can then use the singleton pattern to keep only one instance of this class.

Comment: `Singleton` in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx.  NB: Singletons are considered an anit-pattern in many scenarios, so please use caution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons.  Depending on your scenario, consider `Dependency Injection`: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have static variables and don't want to make this class a singleton, the way around is to wrap static variables:

```
[XmlElement("VNC1Location")]
public string VNC1LocationLocal
{
    get
    {
        return VNC1Location;
    }
    set
    {
        VNC1Location = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have added this into my VNCVars class and when I generate the XML file VNC1LocationLocal is there with the Value that I have entered into Public Static String VNCLocation1.

So as well as 
 private static string strVNC1Location;
        public static string VNC1Location
        {
            get { return strVNC1Location; }
            set { strVNC1Location = value; }
        }

Do i need the corresponding 
public string VNC1LocationLocal
{
    get
    {
        return VNC1Location;
    }
    set
    {
        VNC1Location = value;
    }
}

to make it work??

Comment: Yes, you need `VNC1LocationLocal` property (name is irrelevant) to serialize `VNC1Location` static property. I forgot that my code will generate `<VNC1LocationLocal>` element in xml. You need to add `XmlElement` attribute with desired xml name to generate proper xml.
I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Does it work for you? Or maybe you have more questions?